# Get rid of duplicate items in ComboBox from a BLOB database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, blob

I am getting duplicate items in a combobox that displays saved BLOBs in my database.

```
Private Sub refreshBLOBList()
    Dim getBLOBListCommand As New SqlCommand( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM DocumentStorage", dbConnection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    getBLOBListCommand.Connection.Open()
    reader = getBLOBListCommand.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        BLOBList.Items.Add(reader(0))
    End While

    reader.Close()
    getBLOBListCommand.Connection.Close()

    BLOBList.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

In this block I refresh the combobox, but DISTINCT doesn't get rid of the dupes in the combobox. The weird thing is, when I query it and put it in a datagridview I get the dataset I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to call `BLOBList.Clear()` before adding your items. Otherwise you'll just add all the distinct new ones again

Comment: @FloatingKiwi You were right, that fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call BLOBlist.items.clear() before I added items otherwise I will add the distinct ones again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "DISTINCT". Just BLOBList.items.clear()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your answer to provide a few more details?